# How to implement a circle button like below one in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am working on developing logical connectors on XAML but got stuck in generating 
AND connector

[image]

Code:

```
    <Grid> 
       <Ellipse Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Black"></Ellipse>   
       <Button> <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" >+</TextBlock> </Button>      
       <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="5"> </Ellipse> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Okay, so where do you stuck ? codes maybe?

Comment: I want to draw ADD component like that
http://imgur.com/DT4bqtL

Comment: I am not able to draw lines inside the circle

Comment: When  you say _"circle"_ do you mean _ellipse_ because what you show `isn't entirely round`.

Comment: Whatever your code is.. You should have to post here...

Comment: <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Black"></Ellipse>
                        <Button>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       >+</TextBlock>
                        </Button>
                        <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="5">
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Grid>

Comment: @AbhishekJadaun You can place your code in your question.  Just **edit** it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer by adding path data

```
<Grid >
                    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
                    <Path Data="M10,0 L10,20 z" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"  />
                  <Path Data="M0,10 L20,10 z" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"  />
                </Grid>
```